# temporary user profile on windows

Tags: windows, users, user-accounts, user-profile, profile

everytime I log into the computer I am getting Message you are logged in With a temporary user profile. How can I fix this problem? I set up pc With New Windows 7 still i am getting the Message. I am not logged in as my user, but as TEMP-user each time. Any solution that work?

Answer (score 0):

A bad profile mean your own profile is corrupted or the default's profile on the workstation is corrupted if you haven't logged into that workstation yet.

Backup your data and delete your local profile and let the system recreate your folder is the best solution.

Check there to see if a profile is already there: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProfileList, after Use My Computer or Windows Explorer to remove the appropriate Windows\Profiles\User name folders.